# GraphQL ignore unnessary fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I am working on a Node project using graphql-js. I've been extremely happy with GraphQL over REST, except one issue - GraphQL by default will reject inputs containing unknown/unneeded fields. This is especially annoying when using apollo-client, which adds __typename to every requested object. There's [an issue](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/issues/235) to change this functionality in GraphQL, but I'm wondering what's the best way to go from here. Right now I have to manually clean my objects before sending anything.

So I'm doing this before most network requests:

```
delete person.__typename
for(const tag in person.tags) {
   delete tag.__typename
}
```

Which isn't nice nor efficient. What's the best way to handle this?